# Partition groups into subcollections of isomorphic groups - Fraleigh p. 84 8.10 (please revamp title if necessary)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here a * superscript means
all nonzero elements of the set. The orange is the answer. 
[image]

Then S = $\{C_1, ..., C_9\}$ is a partition of the given
collection into subcollections of isomorphic groups.
Notice that C1 consists of all the infinite cyclic groups;
C2 consists of the cyclic groups of order 2;
C3 consists of the cyclic groups of order 6;
C4's groups are isomorphic due to $ln : \langle \mathbb{R}^+, \cdot \rangle \rightarrow  \langle \mathbb{R}, \cdot \rangle$
 C5 contains the only non-abelian group in the collection;

C6 isn't cyclic, and is countably infinite. but notice $\langle \mathbb{Q}*, \cdot \rangle$ is not isomorphic to
$\langle \mathbb{Q}, + \rangle$ since 
$x*x = id \implies \begin{cases} x \cdot x = 1 \text{ has two solutions in } \langle \mathbb{Q}*, \cdot \rangle \\ x + x = 0, \text{has one solution in } \langle \mathbb{Q}, + \rangle \end{cases}$;

(C7.) the solutions of the equation $x^2 = 1$ in $\langle \mathbb{R}^*, \cdot \rangle$ and
$\langle \mathbb{R}^+, \cdot \rangle$ show these groups are non-isomorphic.
$x*x = 1 \implies \begin{cases} x \cdot x = 1 \text{ has two solutions in } \langle \mathbb{R}^*, \cdot \rangle \\ x + x = 1, \text{has one solution in } \langle \mathbb{R}^+, \cdot \rangle \end{cases}$

(C8.) Finally the equation $x^4 = 1$ has four solutions in $\mathbb{C}$. This distinguishes $\langle \mathbb{C}*, \cdot \rangle$ from all the other
infinite groups in the collection. I know $x^4 = 1 \implies x = \pm 1, \pm i$.

> (1.) What's a smart efficient way to do this? I know to determine if two groups are isomorphic, then a first bid is to use cardinality. If they don't have the same cardinality, they can't be isomorphic. Then what?
>
> (2.) (By dint of fkraiem's answer) How and why is it true for any two groups:
>   "The different number of solutions to any equation involving the identity (like $x*x = \mathrm{id}$) means that if you try to construct an isomorphism, you will run into a contradiction."
>
> I want to use this in general, hence do you need to prove this? Or is there intuition?
>   I see groups C6, C7 differ in their number of solutions to $x * x = id$.
>
> (3.) The trick to fkraiem's answer is to write [$\phi(1) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/647697/53934) as $\phi((-1)\times(-1))$. Does this work on the whole? How do you predestine this trick?

Answer (score 1):

(2.) The different number of solutions to $x*x = \mathrm{id}$ (or some other equation involving the identity) means that if you try to construct an isomorphism, you will run into a contradiction. Say I have an isomorphism $\phi: (\mathbf{Q}^*,\times) \to (\mathbf{Q}, +)$. Since it is an isomorphism, I have $\color{brown}{\phi(1) = 0}$.
I write $\phi((-1)\times(-1))$  in two ways.
First, $\phi((-1)\times(-1)) = \color{brown}{\phi(1) = 0}. \quad (♥)$
Secoond, $\phi((-1)\times(-1)) = \phi(-1)+\phi(-1) = 2\phi(-1)$.
By dint of $(♥)$, this $= 0$. Hence $2\phi(-1) = 0$,
contradicting the fact that $\phi$ is an isomorphism and is thus injective.

*EDIT:* In more group-theoretic terms, $(\mathbf{Q},+)$ has no element of order two, while $(\mathbf{Q}^*,\times)$ has one, so they can't be isomorphic, since two isomorphic groups have the same group structure.

*EDIT after OP's edit to his question:*

The fact of the matter is simply what I said in my first edit: two groups are not isomorphic if there is a structural difference between them.

In this case, $\mathbf{Q}$ has no element of order two (there is no non-zero rational $x$ such that $2x = 0$), while $\mathbf{Q}^*$ has one (there is one non-one rational $x$ such that $x^2 = 1$, namely $-1$). If $\phi: \mathbf{Q}^* \to \mathbf{Q}$ is an isomorphism, then for any $x \in \mathbf{Q}^*$ of order two, $\phi(x) \in \mathbf{Q}$ has order two. So $\mathbf{Q}$ has at least one elements of order two, which is absurd since it has none.

And, again, this is only *one* kind of "structural difference", there are others. For example, you can show that $\mathbf{R}^*$ and $\mathbf{C}^*$ are not isomorphic by using the fact that every element of $\mathbf{C}^*$ has a square root, which is not true in $\mathbf{R}^*$. (If $z \in \mathbf{C}^*$ has a square root $a$, then $\phi(z) \in \mathbf{R}^*$ has square root $\phi(a)$...)

Comment: I edited my answer after your edit to your question.

Comment: "Structural difference" is not really a well-defined mathematical term, so you should never use it in a formal argument where you are asked to prove that two groups are not isomorphic. (In general, when you are asked to prove something, then you have to formally prove it, not use some higher-level argument.)

Comment: What do you mean by "notify"?

Comment: Thanks. Oh just getting back to me. Pretend I found that two groups have different number of solutions to $x∗x=id.$ Then what do I do to prove they're not isomorphic? You said  "Structural difference" is badly defined and should never be used formally.

Comment: Say $G$ has three distinct elements $g_1,g_2,g_3$ such that $g_1\cdot g_1 = g_2 \cdot g_2 = g_3\cdot g_3 = \mathrm{id}_G$, and suppose $G'$ is a group isomorphic to $G$, with $\phi: G\to G'$ being an isomorphism. Then automatically $\phi(g_1)\cdot \phi(g_1) = \phi(g_2)\cdot \phi(g_2) = \phi(g_3)\cdot \phi(g_3) = \phi(\mathrm{id}_G) = \mathrm{id}_{G'}$. This means that there are at least three elements $x \in G'$ such that $x\cdot x = \mathrm{id}_{G'}$. If you know that there are actually fewer than three, then this is a contradiction and the groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: thanks. can you plase move your comments into your answer? and why did you write $g_i \cdot g_i = id_G$ for $1 \le i \le 3$? This is true in general for any natural number i?

Comment: @FrankMuer Again, this is only a template. We made the assumption that $G$ has three elements which square to the identity, while $G'$ has less than three. Of course not every group has three elements whih square to the identity, you need to adapt the proof to your situation. I don't believe there is a need to edit my answer, the same thing is already in it.