# Proof verification: For isomorphism $\phi : G\to H$, show that if $e_{G}\in G$ and $e_{H}\in H$, then $\phi (e_{G})=e_{H}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

Could someone please verify my following proof?

> For isomorphism $\phi : G\to H$ for groups $G$ and $H$, show that if identities $e_{G}\in G$ and $e_{H}\in H$, then $\phi (e_{G})=e_{H}$.

**Proof:** Let $e_{G}\in (G,\circ)$ and $e_{H}\in (H,\cdot)$. Then $\phi (e_{G})=\phi (e_{G}\circ e_{G}) = \phi (e_{G})\cdot \phi (e_{G})$. The only idempotent element in the group H is its identity element $e_{H}$. Therefore, $\phi(e_{G})=e_{H}$.

Comment: Seems good, but since this is a simple problem I would recommend explaining why "The only idempotent in the group $H$ is its identity element $e_H$."

Comment: This is true for any homomorphism, your proof is correct. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647697/tricks-prove-homomorphism-maps-identity-to-identity-fraleigh-p-128-theorem

Comment: @user357980 This is often proved as a separate exercise in introductory group theory courses.

Comment: Was this a theorem or a statement that you know that you can use? I just thought that one was something that was on the same level as what you were trying to prove.

Comment: Would it be better if I follow the answer and multiply both sides by the inverse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep since you know that $\phi (e_{G}) = \phi (e_{G})\cdot \phi (e_{G})$. You can multiply both sides with $\phi (e_{G})^{-1}$ and have your result.

Comment: And since $\phi (e_{G})\cdot \phi ^{-1}(e_{G})$ is equal to the identity in $H$, it must be that $\phi (e_{G})=e_{H}$?

Comment: exactly, sorry for the late reply.