# Proving that a group homomorphism maps identity element to identity element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I have a multi-step problem that I'm unsure how to do. I'm given
Let $\varphi:G\rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism between groups $G$ and $G'$. I have to prove the following:

a)If $e$ is the identity element of $G$, then $\varphi(e)$ is the identity element of $G'$.

I'm sorry that I asked multiple things at once. I'm new to this. I did search for my questions, but nothing maybe what I was looking for.
As for what I've tried:
Let $\varphi:G\rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism between groups $G$ and $G'$. Also, let $e$ be the identity element of $G$. Since $\varphi:G\rightarrow G'$
is a homomorphism between groups $G$ and $G'$, then by definition $\varphi(e)$ is the identity element of $G'$.

This doesn't feel right though. I feel like something is missing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Each of these questions has been covered here before. Please search before asking.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/647697/104041).

Comment: You are not proving anything, only saying "by definition" and claiming what you are asked to prove. Write the true definition of a group homomorphism and use it.

Comment: @AnneBauval I second the suggestion to quote the precise definition of "homomorphism" being used. Not sure about "true", though: most "groups, rings, and fields" books define it as a semigroup homomorphism between groups, but some texts/authors (myself included) whoalso want to put it in the context of monoid morphisms (or universal algebra) define them to respect all three group operations.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Right, I should not have used that word. I also thought about that but if the OP is asked to prove it, I thought (may be wrongly) it could not be part of the definition they were given.

Comment: @Tacosi Please excuse me for having been rude. What definition of a group homomorphism were you given? And was it by the same teacher as the one who gave you that task?